# Leaving the controls visible in VLC

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, vlc-media-player

I am using VLC to show video's on the external screen.
But as I cannot see that screen I want to have the controls (with the time etc.) on my normal laptop screen so I know how much time there is left.

There might be a external solution to control VLC that way but so far I just set the time the controls. However, I have installed VLC on another computer and cannot find where this setting is. I can remember that it was hard to find last time, and after spending an hour I still haven't found it.

Can anybody tell me where it is?
I am currently using 2.0.5 for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I think the setting you are looking for is found in the general "Interface" settings and is called "Integrate video in interface".  When this option is not selected videos will open in a separate window and leave the controls separate.

[image: VLC Screenshot]

Comment: Well, I cannot find that option in the Mac Version. But I can remember that the timeout, the amount of seconds (or milliseconds) was a number which could be changed, and I put it to something like 15 minutes which is enough for my purpose